# Is there a way to test the output of a jupyter Notebook file in a python file?

Tags: python, testing, jupyter-notebook

I am currently writing a automated testing program for files in jupyter Notebook.
I want to do this without executing the jupyter Notebook, so i want to test in a .py file.
Is there a way to do that?
Another aspect would be to turn the notebook to a .py file and then test is, but how can i access certain cells within it?

Comment: I'm not following really why you want to test the notebook without executing it? Do you mean without opening it and executing it the normal way? Because there's a lot of options to execute a notebook file from the command line. However, for everything before "Another aspect...", it can be done. There's several options for commands to convert a notebook into a `.py` file using a command. I like [jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html#command-line-conversion) and then in theory you have `.py` you can use in your test.

Comment: The issue is that unless you have used pure python in your notebook, you actually don't want to run it as `.py` because magics and commands that need IPython aren't going to work in Python. If you need those to work, usually you can change the `.py` file to an `.ipy` file that IPython can ran as an IPython script just by changing the extension. Now onto everything after 'Another aspect'... I actually thought your phrase "to test in a .py file" already meant you'd turn the notebook to a Python file. But maybe that is really aside from the point. Are you just wanting to test a certain cell?

Comment: There's a number of ways to access the content of individual cells. Which direction you take can depend a lot on how general or specific you need things to be. And so hopefully you see you need to flesh out what you are asking to get some more targeted advice. Especially since your title and last few sentences seem at odds with your opening sentence, "I am currently writing a automated testing program for files in jupyter Notebook."

Comment: Yes i mean without opening it and executing it the normal way. I have a folder with a lot of notebooks all with the same exercises and i want to test the output of these cells with executing 1 .py or .ipy file.

Comment: There's an even more direct route that I only alluded to because you seemed specific about running each notebook as a script to test it. You can execute the notebooks from the command line **without any conversion**, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/run-ipynb-on-a-remote-workstation-so-that-all-results-will-be-save-in-the-same-pynb/13340/2?u=fomightez) for mention of some. I tend to use on the command line jupytext and papermill just because I learned of & used those first. You aren't specific about what you are testing & how and so it is hard to advise on how to integrate that step.

Comment: Plus there is nbtoolbelt, see [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/how-to-run-a-notebook-using-command-line/3475/14?u=fomightez).